# Xpages: Opening a pre populated xpage from e-mail

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

Is it possible in Xpages when a page is opened from a link it pre populates pre selected fields? In my case i am opening a link to a xpages page from a e-mail and creating a new document with pre selected values in some fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `param` global variable in SSJS (also available in Java) gives a Map of all URL parameters.

If the default values are all the same, whenever it comes from email, just add a URL parameter that you can check in beforePageLoad event.

If you need different defaults for different email links, add the default to those links. The `param` Map can then can be interrogated to set default values.